# How to obtain just the year from pandas data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, time

So I wrote some code to turn a list of strings into date times:

```
s = pd.Series(["14 Nov 2020", "14/11/2020", "2020/11/14", 
          "Hello World", "Nov 14th, 2020"])
s_dates = pd.to_datetime(s, errors='coerce', exact=False)
print(s_dates)
```

It produced the following output:

```
0   2020-11-14
1   2020-11-14
2   2020-11-14
3          NaT
4   2020-11-14
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

How would I obtain just the year from this?

Answer (score 3):

Since your series`s_dates` has dtype `datetime64[ns]`, you can directly use
[`Series.dt.year`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) like:

```
print(s_dates.dt.year)
```

This will return a series containing only the year (as dtype `int64`).

Check the documentation for more useful datetime transformations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your years would always be 4 digits, we can try using `str.extract` here:

```py
s_dates["year"] = s_dates["dates_extracted"].str.extract(r'(\d{4})')
```